# how to prevent XSS attack with php function

Tags: php, xss

I'm using the `htmlspecialchars()` function to prevent XSS attacks but I'm not sure if that is the correct way to prevent such attacks:

```
htmlspecialchars($input_value);
```

If not, what is the best/simplest way to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent XSS with HTML/PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996122/how-to-prevent-xss-with-html-php)

Comment: Correct way is this :- echo htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');